# Does Shar have a stake in the Blood War?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities, baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus

I am currently playing a character in Descent into Avernus who worships Shar.

While my character has their own goals, I'm trying to learn more lore about Shar's dealings with devils and demons and if she has any skin in the Blood War.

The only thing I've found is a reference to her and Selune bringing order from chaos, but that's neither confirmed nor potentially relevant :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blood War is a multiverse-level conflict, and in general deities do not have much to do with it. Shar and Selune are both single-sphere deities, which would arguably make them even less interested in what happens in the war between the baatezu and the tanarri.

The 2e sourcebook Hellbound: The Blood War has a chapter that discusses how deities get involved in the Blood War. Based on their alignment and portfolio, it is described how some deities side with either side of the war from time to time. Neither Shar, nor Selune are present amongst the example deities. Shar, with her self-centered NE personality is unlikely to be much interested in the Blood War.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and lets me be me :)